# debugging objective c memory leak with xCode Leaks

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks

I'm doing my first steps in finding memory leaks in xCode 4.5 and using the Leaks instrument. I found a couple of issues and seemed to fix them, but this one eludes me.

Here is the code:

```
RUBEImageInfo* imgInfo = [[[RUBEImageInfo alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *nm = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:img->name.c_str()];
imgInfo->name = nm;
[imgInfo->name retain]; // I'm using it outside of this method
```

Leaks reports a leak in the second line, with the percentage next to the "i" at %100.

So I tried two things:

One, I marked `nm` with autohrleas like this:

```
NSString *nm = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:img->name.c_str()] autorelease];
```

Two, I also tried calling release on `nm` after it's assignment to `imgInfo->name` so the code looks like this:

```
imgInfo->name = nm; 
[imgInfo->name retain]; 
[nm release];
```

But in both cases the app crashes with BAD_ACCESS when I run it, and call `[imgInfo->name UTF8String]`.

What am I missing?

EDIT following Rob's answer:

This is the RUBEImageInfo class:

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface RUBEImageInfo : NSObject {

@public CCSprite* sprite;               // the image
@public NSString* name;                 // the file the image was loaded from
@public class b2Body* body;             // the body this image is attached to (can be NULL)
@public float scale;                    // a scale of 1 means the image is 1 physics unit high
@public float angle;                    // 'local angle' - relative to the angle of the body
@public CGPoint center;                 // 'local center' - relative to the position of the body
@public float opacity;                  // 0 - 1
@public bool flip;                      // horizontal flip
@public int colorTint[4];               // 0 - 255 RGBA values
}

@end
```

And the .m:

```
#import "RUBEImageInfo.h"

@implementation RUBEImageInfo

// Nothing much to see here. Just make sure the body starts as NULL.
-(id)init
{
    if( (self=[super init])) {
        body = NULL;
}
return self;
}

-(void) dealloc {
    [name release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: **Do not EVER use `->` to set or retrieve values in an object.** That is just flat out the wrong thing to do.  It is fragile, breaks encapsulation, and is simply not used.

Comment: So @bbum what would you do instead?

Comment: Call the setters/getters via dot syntax or normal method syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of reactions:

1. Instruments identified where the leaked object was allocated, but in this case, this code might not be the source of the leak. You should:

   - ensure you `release` the `name` in the `dealloc` method of `RUBEImageInfo`; and
   - also, if you're setting `name` a second time, make sure you `release` the previous `name` object before you set it to a new object.
2. Your life will be much easier if you use [declared properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/DeclaredProperty.html) rather than dereferencing class instance variables. For example, if `name` was declared as:

   ```
   @property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name; // you could use `retain`, too, but `copy` is safer when dealing with strings
   ```

   Then you would set the `name` property as so:

   ```
   RUBEImageInfo* imgInfo = [[[RUBEImageInfo alloc] init] autorelease];
   NSString *nm = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:img->name.c_str()];
   imgInfo.name = nm;
   // this is no longer needed as the `name` setter will take care of memory semantics
   // [imgInfo->name retain]; // I'm using it outside of this method
   ```

   By using the setter accessor method (i.e. the "dot syntax" of `imgInfo.name`), it will take care of a lot of routine memory semantics of releasing any previous object that `name` may have referenced, and it will do the necessary `copy` or `retain`. Obviously, the `RUBEImageInfo` method `dealloc` still needs to release `name`, but at least it simplifies the memory semantics of the `name` property of `RUBEImageInfo` objects.
3. Since you are using manual reference counting, I'd encourage you to investigate the "static analyzer" (invoked by selecting "Analyze" from Xcode's "Product" menu). The Leaks tool in Instruments will tell you what leaked, but it doesn't tell you where the leak happened; it has no way of knowing; it can only show you where the leaked object was allocated and you'll have to hunt down the logic error yourself. The static analyzer can sometimes point out errors that lead to leaks, but more importantly, show you where the leak was caused, rather than just where the leaked object was originally instantiated. You should have a clean bill of health from the static analyzer before you even bother running Instruments.

---

Looking at your code sample, if you're not going to use declared properties (not sure why you wouldn't, as it makes life easier, but to each his own), I'd suggest making sure you initialize all of your objects in `init` and `release` all of them in `dealloc`:

```
@implementation RUBEImageInfo

-(id)init
{
    if ((self=[super init])) {
        body = NULL;
        name = nil;
        sprite = nil;
        // I might initialize other class instance variables here, too, but that's up to you
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) dealloc {
    [name release];
    // shouldn't you release `body` and `sprite`, too?
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Then your code that sets the `name` instance variable would make sure to `release` the previous object before setting the new object. Thus the initial instantiation might look like:

```
RUBEImageInfo* imgInfo = [[[RUBEImageInfo alloc] init] autorelease];
NSString *nm = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:img->name.c_str()];
imgInfo->name = [nm retain]; // retain the new object
```

But if you update it later, you should:

```
NSString *nm = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:someNewImg->name.c_str()];
[imageInfo->name release];   // release the old one
imgInfo->name = [nm retain]; // retain the new object
```

Comment: Thanks, Rob. I tried releasing the name in the RUBEImageInfo dealloc method but the leak is still there. (And Analyze doesn't report anything there.) I edited the question to add the class in question.

Comment: @Eddy Are you setting `name` again later? If so, you should `release` it like shown in my revised answer. If you omitted this `release`, Instruments would show the leaked string back where you originally instantiated `imgInfo`. If you're not setting the `name` instance variable again, like shown in my final code sample, then you must have something else retaining the string object referenced by `name`.

Comment: @Eddy By the way, if you're still leaking `name`, I'd temporarily put a breakpoint or NSLog statement in `dealloc` and make sure it's getting called (if not, the leaking `name` is a symptom of a broader problem, the leaking of `imgInfo`), and if it is called, examine the `[name retainCount]` (it should be `1` right before you do the `release` ... if not you've got something else retaining `name`).

Comment: Looks like the real issue is in a C++ library that I haven't written. Either in the library, or in my use of it. I'm continuing to investigate but anyway I think you gave me all the info you can on this issue, and moved me forward. So thanks, and I'm happily accepting the answer :)